# A dictionary has a separate dictionary and i want to convert it in dataframe in python such that the table contains columns which has sub columns

Tags: python, database, data-structures

```
Data=[{'endDate': {'raw': 1585612800, 'fmt': '2020-03-31'},
      'totalRevenue': {'raw': 67985000, 'fmt': '67.98M', 'longFmt': 
       '67,985,000'},
       'costOfRevenue': {'raw': 0, 'fmt': None, 'longFmt': '0'},
       'grossProfit': {'raw': 67985000, 'fmt': '67.98M', 'longFmt': 
        '67,985,000'},
       'sellingGeneralAdministrative': {'raw': 37779000,
        'fmt': '37.78M'}},
     {'endDate': {'raw': 1577750400, 'fmt': '2019-12-31'},
       'totalRevenue': {'raw': 79115000, 'fmt': '79.11M', 'longFmt': 
        '79,115,000'},
       'costOfRevenue': {'raw': 0, 'fmt': None, 'longFmt': '0'},
       'grossProfit': {'raw': 79115000, 'fmt': '79.11M', 'longFmt': 
        '79,115,000'},
       ' sellingGeneralAdministrative': {'raw': 36792000,
        'fmt': '36.79M',
        'longFmt': '36,792,000'}}]
 

   i want Data in this format

 Data =[{endDate:{'fmt':'2020-03-31'},
      totalRevenue:{'fmt':67.98M},
      costofRevenue:{'fmt':None}' and so on
```

i.e removing 'raw' and 'longfmt'
and after that i want it to convert the list of dict to dataframe.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the format you want is? And maybe [edit] your tags to be specific to the library you're using (the term "dataframe" often means [tag:pandas], but not always). If you're using a database, tag the specific one! And maybe show your current code that converts from your list of dicts into the other format.

Comment: i want the grossProfit column should have 3 columns of raw ,fmt and longFmt and same for the other coulmns (income before tax , income tax expense )

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do to convert multiple dictionaries like that into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

a = {...}
b = {...}

c = [a, b]
f = {'grossProfit':[], 'incomeBeforeTax':[], 'incomeTaxExpense':[]}
for e in c:
    for k in f.keys():
        f[d].append(e[d])

print(pd.DataFrame(f))
```

Comment: i have send you only the one set but it has many more set of similar dictionaries . I have also aplied the same code and got the result as shown in my img..

Comment: I have updated my dictionary set . It is a list of dictionary with subdictionary in it.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` doesn't *actually* support "sub-columns", as it seems you're requesting. It does, though, support flattening `json` objects in a way that `{'a': {'b': 'value'}}` gives you column `a.b = 'value'`. The official method for performing this is `json_normalize`, and would be used like such

```py
import pandas as pd

income_statement_history = {
    "totalRevenue": {
        "raw": 67985000,
        "fmt": "67.98M",
        "longFmt": "67,985,000"
    },
    "costOfRevenue": {
        "raw": 0,
        "fmt": 'null',
        "longFmt": "0"
    },
    "grossProfit": {
        "raw": 67985000,
        "fmt": "67.98M",
        "longFmt": "67,985,000"
    },
    "totalOperatingExpenses": {
        "raw": 46790000,
        "fmt": "46.79M",
        "longFmt": "46,790,000"
    },
    "operatingIncome": {
        "raw": 21195000,
        "fmt": "21.2M",
        "longFmt": "21,195,000"
    }
}

df = pd.json_normalize(income_statement_history)
```

And printing `df` would give you

```py
>>> df
   totalRevenue.raw totalRevenue.fmt totalRevenue.longFmt  costOfRevenue.raw costOfRevenue.fmt  ... totalOperatingExpenses.fmt  totalOperatingExpenses.longFmt operatingIncome.raw operatingIncome.fmt  operatingIncome.longFmt     
0          67985000           67.98M           67,985,000                  0              null  ...                     46.79M                      46,790,000            21195000               21.2M               21,195,000     

[1 rows x 15 columns]
```

You could proceed to dynamically access those column values with

```py
>>> col = 'totalOperatingExpenses'
>>> subcol = 'longFmt'
>>> df[f'{col}.{subcol}']
0    46,790,000
Name: totalOperatingExpenses.longFmt, dtype: object
```

---

Deciding between this, a `pd.DataFrame` initialization as @Ann Zen's answer suggests, or whatever method you've been using, depends on your **exact need**.

Is your goal a visually pleasing disposition of columns based on json data? Is your goal a clear way of accessing a sub-column given its name and the name of the base column? Most answers I can think of are based on preference only, and the differences are minimal.

Comment: Thanks that realy helps but  its showing error with the pd.json_normalise.  I have used    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize and then df=json_normalize(income_statement_history)

Comment: What error exactly? And what data did you put as `income_statement_history`? It seems you are doing something different - all code in this answer comes from already done executions in Python 3.x